# GAE "Ran 0 tests" from unittest2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unit-testing

I'm attempting to implement unit tests as per GAE's Python SDK [Setting up a testing framework](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Python_Setting_up_a_testing_framework) section.

Using their sample test runner and test, I receive the following output:

> Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
>
> OK

I have unittest2 installed and I also tried running the following commands, but all yielded the same response:

```
python -m unittest discover ~/foldername
python -m unittest2 discover ~/foldername
```

I tried adding the [Basic example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) test file  from Python docs, but also got the same result.

Tried all of above with and without an `__init__.py` in the unit test's folder.

What should I try next to debug this issue?

**Update**

My directory structure is as below:

```
├── app.yaml
├── myclass.py
├── bulkloader.yaml
├── myappname.py
├── index.yaml
├── testmodel.py
├── test_runner.py
└── unit_tests
    ├── demotestcase.py
    └── sample.py
```

With the contents of both tests from the above referenced links.

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? What does the inside of the files look like?

Comment: updated with directory structure, files as linked

Answer (score 0):

```
Usage: python -m unittest discover [options]

-s directory     Directory to start discovery ('.' default)
-p pattern       Pattern to match test files ('test*.py' default)
```